# Email uniquness validate in jsf

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

Here is my `JSF` form email code section:

(`Registration.xhtml`)

```
<p:inputText id="email" required="true" label="Email" size="20" value="#{registrationBean.email}">
<f:validateRegex pattern="([^.@]+)(\.[^.@]+)*@([^.@]+\.)+([^.@]+)"/>
<f:validator id="uniqueEmailValidator"/>
</p:inputText>
 <h:message for="email"/>
```

And this is my validator class:

```
@FacesValidator("uniqueEmailValidator")
public class UniqueEmailValidator implements Validator {

    @Override
    public void validate(FacesContext fc, UIComponent uic, Object value) throws ValidatorException {
        if (value == null) {
            return;
        }
        String email = (String) value;
        CustomerService cService = new CustomerService();
        if (!cService.exists(email)) {
            throw new ValidatorException(new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "mail is already in use.", "error"));
        }
      }
   }
```

I got this error when to run the application:

```
/Registration.xhtml @49,73 <f:validator> A validator id was not specified. Typically the validator id is set in the constructor ValidateHandler(ValidatorConfig)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your f:validator tag, change "id" to "validatorId"

```
<f:validator validatorId="uniqueEmailValidator"/>
```